# python argparse limit arg values action API?

Tags: python, python-2.7

The following snipped calls parse_args() to identify a parameter --num and that tests that the value is acceptable in separate code after parsing.

```
import argparse

def cmd_line_opts(cmdline):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="blah blah",)

    parser.add_argument('--num', default=None, type=int,)

    return parser.parse_args(cmdline)

p = cmd_line_opts(['--num', '2'])
if p.num < 1:
    raise ValueError('--num must be > 0')

p = cmd_line_opts(['--num', '0'])
if p.num < 1:
    raise ValueError('--num must be > 0')
```

I am wondering if it would be possible to include the test and a suitable error message directly in the parsing. I suspect that this involves using the [Action API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action-classes) but I can't figure out how to signal a failure when returning from the action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a custom type for the argument.

```
def positive_int(s):
    try:
        s = int(s)
        if s <= 0:
            raise ValueError()
    except ValueError:
        raise ArgumentTypeError("Not a valid positive integer: {}".format(s))

# ...
parser.add_argument("--num", type=positive_int, default=0)
```

The `type` argument is any callable that accepts a string and returns a value to use for the argument's value. It doesn't have to be an actual type (built-in or otherwise).

Comment: Perfect answer, thanke @chepner!

On my config I to change the "raise ArgumentTypeError"  to "raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError".

Answer (score 0):

Full credit to @chepner for his answer, above. At least on my system you need qualify ArgumentTypeError. I put it in a comment but thought it would be helpful to someone who just wanted to copy and paste the code.

```
import argparse

def positive_int(s):
    try:
        s = int(s)
        if s <= 0:
            raise ValueError()
    except ValueError:
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError("Not a valid positive integer: {}".format(s))

def cmd_line_opts(cmdline):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="blah blah",)
    parser.add_argument("--num", type=positive_int, default=0)
    return parser.parse_args(cmdline)

p = cmd_line_opts(['--num', 'x'])
```